# JS: Why is the Event object accessible in event handlers without accepting it in a parameter?

Tags: javascript, events, arguments, language-design

While looking back over some JS I'd written in the past, I noticed that I was trying to access `event.keyCode` in an event handler, but my function's only parameter was `e`, not `event`. So, while I would expect to get a `"Uncaught ReferenceError: event is not defined"`, I instead found that my script works as expected (at least in Chrome).

```
document.body.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
    if (event.keyCode === 13) {
        // ...
    }
});
```

In fact, if I place a `console.log(e === event)` in that handler, I get `true`.
After a little testing (in [a JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/pujamup/edit?js,console,output)) it seems like this must apply to every such event, making `event` another sort of "sly" local variable like [`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) that appears in a function without asking for it in a parameter.

This makes me wonder:

1. Are these the only two "sly" local variables?
2. Is this behavior with `event` in Chrome consistent with other browsers & JS environments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the browser, there is a global [`event`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/event) variable that refers to the currently fired event.

Comment: Oh, I just assumed it was local. Hmm.

Comment: @Web_Designer iirc, there was once a time where event handlers did `var event  = event || window.event` to make sure they got a handle on the event, global or local. I think it was IE's `attachEvent` that didn't pass in `event` as handler argument.

Comment: Now that you mention it, I have seen that before, but never used it. How would that have helped to get a handle on the event? Was the object once not passed as an argument to event handlers?